# VirtualBox - Create Virtual machine from host OS as a clone

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualbox, portability

I am only starting out with virtualbox and ubuntu OS. I have used windows 10 and was wondering if I can clone the windows host os, files and programs for use as a virtual machine. And I would like to do the same with ubuntu.

The goal is to be able to take what I have been using on Windows 10 to my Ubuntu OS.

A few more questions:
-Could VirtualBox be used from a bootable drive to then use any OS I have cloned (a portable version of all my personal computers)? I would like to eventually have windows 95, 7, XP, 10, and ubuntu on virtualbox and preferable portable.
-If it is not possible to clone the host windows 10, is it possible to use a digital licence (licence aquired from free upgrade from windows 7) to create a virtual machine in virtualBox. I dont have a product key.

Thanks for any help. If you need any clarrification or further information I'll get back to you as soon as I can. Im in the middle of moving house and trying to update my technology.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to anyone that may have read but after more research I found a solution. I was using the incorrect terminology.

Regarding cloning the physical disk to be imported into virtualbox:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=79879

Regarding portable virtualbox:
http://www.vbox.me/

Regarding Windows 10 digital licences: 
They will only work on the same hardware. Virtualbox should run windows 10 if you are on the same pc that windows 10 was initially installed on. If you change pc it will not work because the hardware fingerprint is different.

Hope this helps anyone else.